# Does it follow that $(n!)^n$ divide $(n^2)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

It is well known that $(n!)^2$ divides $(2n)!$.

Does it follow that $(n!)^3$ divides $(3n)!$ and so on up to $(n!)^n$ dividing $(n^2)!$?

If yes or no, could you provide the details behind the argument?

As a quick test, I tried $n=3$ and $n=4$ which worked.

Thanks,

-Larry

Comment: You conjecture holds for every $n$ up to $200$. So I think it's reasonable to expect that it is true.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's true. The simple argument: $\displaystyle \frac{(kn)!}{(n!)^{k}}$ for $1\leq k \leq n$ is equal [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials): $$\displaystyle {kn \choose n,n,\cdots,n}$$.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I had never heard about multinomials before.  Fascinating.